# JavaScript help - JQuery is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I am trying to use DataTables in my page, and for some reason, I am getting "JQuery is undefined" errors when viewing the errors in my browser.  Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/CensusDatabase/js/jquery.dataTables-1.9.4.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CensusDatabase/js/DrawTable.js" ></script>

<head>
    <title>My Census Data</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            color: black;
            background-color: #ffaacc;
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Calibri", sans-serif 
        }
        h1 {
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Calibri", sans-serif
        }

   </style>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>My Census Data</h1>

    <div class="census">

        <div id="block-system-main">
            <h2>Reports</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="nationalAgeGender()">National age and gender data</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="arizonaAgeGender()">Arizona age and gender data</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="combinedAgeGender()">Combined age and gender data</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="nationalRace()">National race data</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="arizonaRace()">Arizona race data</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="combinedRace()">Combined race data</a></li>
                </ul>
        <div id="reportsData"><i>Please select a list to display.</i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
function nationalAgeGender() {
    (function($) {
        $('#data').html('<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" id="data-entry"></table>');
            $('#data-entry').dataTable({
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bScrollInfinite": true,
                "sScrollX": "160%",
                "bScrollCollapse": true ,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "sScrollY": "100%",     
                "iDisplayLength": -1,
                "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom">',
                "aaSorting": [],
                "sAjaxSource": "/CensusDatabase/database_scripts/NationalAgeGender.php",
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "sTitle": "Age group" },
                    { "sTitle": "Total population (both genders)" },
                    { "sTitle": "Male population" },
                    { "sTitle": "Female population" },
                    { "sTitle": "% (both genders)" },
                    { "sTitle": "Male %" },
                    { "sTitle": "Female %" }
                ]

            });
        })(jQuery);
 }

function arizonaAgeGender() {
(function($) {
    $('#data').html('<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" id="data-entry"></table>');
    $('#data-entry').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bScrollInfinite": true,
        "sScrollX": "160%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true ,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sScrollY": "100%",     
        "iDisplayLength": -1,
        "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom">',
        "aaSorting": [],
        "sAjaxSource": "/CensusDatabase/database_scripts/ArizonaAgeGender.php",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sTitle": "Age group" },
            { "sTitle": "Total population (both genders)" },
            { "sTitle": "Male population" },
            { "sTitle": "Female population" },
            { "sTitle": "% (both genders)" },
            { "sTitle": "Male %" },
            { "sTitle": "Female %" }

        ]

    });
})(jQuery);
}

function combinedAgeGender() {
(function($) {
    $('#data').html('<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" id="data-entry"></table>');
    $('#data-entry').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bScrollInfinite": true,
        "sScrollX": "160%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true ,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sScrollY": "100%",     
        "iDisplayLength": -1,
        "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom">',
        "aaSorting": [],
        "sAjaxSource": "/CensusDatabase/database_scripts/CombinedAgeGender.php",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sTitle": "Age group" },
            { "sTitle": "National total population (both genders)" },
            { "sTitle": "National male population" },
            { "sTitle": "National female population" },
            { "sTitle": "National % (both genders)" },
            { "sTitle": "National male %" },
            { "sTitle": "National female %" },
            { "sTitle": "Arizona total population (both genders)" },
            { "sTitle": "Arizona male population" },
            { "sTitle": "Arizona female population" },
            { "sTitle": "Arizona % (both genders)" },
            { "sTitle": "Arizona male %" },
            { "sTitle": "Arizona female %" }
        ]

    });
})(jQuery);
}

function nationalRace() {
(function($) {
    $('#data').html('<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" id="data-entry"></table>');
    $('#data-entry').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bScrollInfinite": true,
        "sScrollX": "160%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true ,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sScrollY": "100%",     
        "iDisplayLength": -1,
        "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom">',
        "aaSorting": [],
        "sAjaxSource": "/CensusDatabase/database_scripts/NationalRace.php",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sTitle": "Category" },
            { "sTitle": "White" },
            { "sTitle": "White %" },
            { "sTitle": "Black or African-American" },
            { "sTitle": "Black or African-American %" },
            { "sTitle": "Native American" },
            { "sTitle": "Native American %" },
            { "sTitle": "Asian" },
            { "sTitle": "Asian %" },
            { "sTitle": "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander" },
            { "sTitle": "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander %" },
            { "sTitle": "Some other race" },
            { "sTitle": "Some other race %" }
        ]

    });
})(jQuery); 
}

function arizonaRace() {
(function($) {
    $('#data').html('<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" id="data-entry"></table>');
    $('#data-entry').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bScrollInfinite": true,
        "sScrollX": "160%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true ,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sScrollY": "100%",     
        "iDisplayLength": -1,
        "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom">',
        "aaSorting": [],
        "sAjaxSource": "/CensusDatabase/database_scripts/ArizonaRace.php",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sTitle": "Category" },
            { "sTitle": "White" },
            { "sTitle": "White %" },
            { "sTitle": "Black or African-American" },
            { "sTitle": "Black or African-American %" },
            { "sTitle": "Native American" },
            { "sTitle": "Native American %" },
            { "sTitle": "Asian" },
            { "sTitle": "Asian %" },
            { "sTitle": "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander" },
            { "sTitle": "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander %" },
            { "sTitle": "Some other race" },
            { "sTitle": "Some other race %" }
        ]

    });
})(jQuery); 
}

function combinedRace() {
(function($) {
    $('#data').html('<table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" id="data-entry"></table>');
    $('#data-entry').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bScrollInfinite": true,
        "sScrollX": "160%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true ,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sScrollY": "100%",     
        "iDisplayLength": -1,
        "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom">',
        "aaSorting": [],
        "sAjaxSource": "/CensusDatabase/database_scripts/NationalRace.php",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sTitle": "Category" },
            { "sTitle": "White (National)" },
            { "sTitle": "White % (National)" },
            { "sTitle": "Black or African-American (National)" },
            { "sTitle": "Black or African-American % (National)" },
            { "sTitle": "Native American (National)" },
            { "sTitle": "Native American % (National)" },
            { "sTitle": "Asian (National)" },
            { "sTitle": "Asian % (National)" },
            { "sTitle": "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander (National)" },
            { "sTitle": "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander % (National)" },
            { "sTitle": "Some other race (National)" },
            { "sTitle": "Some other race % (National)" },,
            { "sTitle": "White (Arizona)" },
            { "sTitle": "White % (Arizona)" },
            { "sTitle": "Black or African-American (Arizona)" },
            { "sTitle": "Black or African-American % (Arizona)" },
            { "sTitle": "Native American (Arizona)" },
            { "sTitle": "Native American % (Arizona)" },
            { "sTitle": "Asian (Arizona)" },
            { "sTitle": "Asian % (Arizona)" },
            { "sTitle": "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander (Arizona)" },
            { "sTitle": "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander % (Arizona)" },
            { "sTitle": "Some other race (Arizona)" },
            { "sTitle": "Some other race % (Arizona)" }
        ]

    });
})(jQuery); 
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: I don't see that you've actually included jQuery in that page.

Comment: I recommend to read http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery.

Comment: You're also missing your `<html>` tag.

Comment: I also don't see a `<html>` element, or closing `</body>`

Comment: And `script` tags should go inside the `head` or `body`.

Answer (score 6):

Seem like you're not include jQuery library:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that this needs to come **before** any code that uses jQuery, which isn't always obvious to everyone (meaning, before the two external files included on the page)